# How to get data from mysql and extract data from web using spider in scrapy

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a spider and pipeline 
and write a code to get extract data from web and insert to MySQL
Which is running

```
class AmazonAllDepartmentSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "amazon"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.amazon.com/gp/site-directory/ref=nav_sad/187-3757581-3331414"
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul[@class="nav_cat_links"]/li'):
            item = AmazoncrawlerItem()
            # pop()  removes [u'']  tag from 
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract().pop()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract().pop()
            item['desc'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            yield item
```

and

```
class AmazoncrawlerPipeline(object):
    host = 'qwerty.com'
    user = 'qwerty'
    password = 'qwerty123'
    db = 'amazon_project'

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = MySQLdb.connect(self.host, self.user, self.password, self.db)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):    
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO amazon_project.ProductDepartment (ProductTitle,ProductDepartmentLilnk)
                            VALUES (%s,%s)""", 
                           (item['title'],'amazon.com' + str(item.get('link'))))


            self.connection.commit()

        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
        return item
```

Now I want to get those data (which is a link of URL)
And again call spider to extract data from web

please help me how to do it  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be solved on the spider level.

To follow the links, you can `yield` a `Request` after `yield`ing an item instance:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//ul[@class="nav_cat_links"]/li'):
        item = AmazoncrawlerItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract().pop()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract().pop()
        item['desc'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
        yield item
        yield Request(item['link'], callback=self.parse_link)
```

Alternatively, you can change the tactics and switch to [`Link Extractors`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html).

---

UPD (after discussion in comments):

If you have the links in the database already, you would need to start another spider, read the links from the database in [`start_requests()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests) and `yield` requests:

```
from scrapy.http import Request

class AmazonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "amazon"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
         connection = MySQLdb.connect(<connection params here>)
         cursor = connection.cursor()

         cursor.execute("SELECT ProductDepartmentLilnk FROM amazon_project.ProductDepartment")
         links = cursor.fetchall()

         for link in links:
              yield Request(link, callback=self.parse)

         cursor.close()

     ...
```

Comment: thanks again sir,i don't know what will be good but what i am thinking i want to call one method which get data from db then crawl web then insert to db and again and again please suggest me feasible way and i called def parse_link(self, response):
print 'anurag sharma' but it's not printed on console

Comment: @anurag this is what I've tried to explain - instead of writing to the database and then reading the links, follow them while you have them in the hands. Does it make sense to you? Thanks.

Comment: actually right now we are able to get 176 link from amazon and we have need to crawl for next 90 links but we have to keep all links in DB. can we do that one by one process first get data from web and save in DB then again get data from db and extract from web and save in DB

Comment: but first time we have nothing then how to fetch from db? Thanks